# How can I immediately terminate a Thread? (Not interrupt)

Tags: java, multithreading

This is not a question about how to cleanly terminate a thread, ie by calling interrupt on it and having the thread respond appropriately. I cannot modify code the thread is executing in any way.

I specifically want to immediately terminate a Thread, I don't care at all what state things are left in. I know something similar is possible using Thread.stop, however this actually throws a ThreadDeath exception, and for the Thread to terminate this exception cannot be caught. However the code I am dealing with catches this exception and is not rethrowing it.

Thread.destroy() seemed to be what I was looking for, however this method was never implemented. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: You do interrupt, and it will stop execution and be gc'ed in the next cycle. What is the issue?

Comment: Doesn't interrupt just set the interrupt flag, or throw an exception? (Which are being caught in the code I'm dealing with) The thread never actually stops executing, just has a flag set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that there's no way in Java to just kill off a thread like you're describing. As you note in a comment, `interrupt` won't do what you want. If the thread is executing, it just sets a flag and it's up to the thread to notice it. if the thread is waiting or sleeping, it will throw an `InterruptedException`.

The only way I can imagine doing what you're describing is to kill the process in which the thread is running. (E.g., call `System.exit(int)`.)

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was hoping for, but the one I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't a way. From `Java Concurrency in Practice`:

> Since there is no preemptive way to stop a thread, they must instead
>   be persuaded to shut down on their own.

Interrupting a thread is not the cleaner way as you said. Clean ways could be:

1. ExecutorService.shutdown()
2. Future.cancel()
3. Poison Pills

You aren't meant to submit tasks to `threads` that take ages to be done. You would rather divide them into smaller tasks and send a `poison pill` to cancel the bigger task. If there is not a way to do that, then `spawn/fork` a `process` and kill it if you want to cancel the task.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust the thread in question to the point that you need to kill it, you would probably be better off running it in a separate process, and kill the process instead.

Anyway, the following code might work if you are ok with the deprecated `Thread` methods:

```
    while (theThread.isAlive()) {
        theThread.stop();
    }
```

Depending on how badly the thread is trying to survive…

You might want to run this code in several threads or repeat the `stop()` call if that's not enough. However, I managed to kill the following thread with this code:

```
    final Thread iWontDie = new Thread(() -> {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("I'm still alive! " + ++i);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // eat t
            }
        }
    });
    iWontDie.start();
```

Comment: This technique won't always work. From the [Java SE Documentation on deprecated `Thread` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html): _"It should be noted that in all situations where a waiting thread doesn't respond to_ `Thread.interrupt`, _it wouldn't respond to_ `Thread.stop` _either._  Such cases include deliberate denial-of-service attacks, and I/O operations for which thread.stop and thread.interrupt do not work properly."

Comment: I like this answer, and it works for the example I mentioned in the question about catching ThreadDeath, because stop is called when it is in the catch block at which point the ThreadDeath error is again thrown and can now propagate up properly. However as Ted Hopp mentions this doesn't necessarily always work, in particular if a thread is (deadlocked) trying to obtain a monitor, it will not respond to stop. Still, I like the way you think, spam it with stops until it dies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 7 or earlier, you could use the overloaded [stop(Throwable obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop(java.lang.Throwable)) method to throw something besides a `ThreadDeath` error:

> Forces the thread to stop executing. If the argument `obj` is `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown (in the current thread). The thread represented by this thread is forced to stop whatever it is doing abnormally and to throw the `Throwable` object `obj` as an exception. This is an unusual action to take; normally, the stop method that takes no arguments should be used.

This method, like the parameterless version, is deprecated, so just keep that in mind.

Comment: Interestingly, the `stop(Throwable obj)` method in Java 8 will always throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` and will not actually kill the thread.